# $xml->writeData(); not working on ExcelWriterXML

Tags: php, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I am running this on MAC, the xml file is creating but the data is not written into the file. Please, Kindly help. Thanks

```
<?php

   include('ExcelWriterXML.php');

    /**
     * @source
     */
    $xml->docTitle('My Demo Doc');
    $xml->docAuthor('Robert F Greer');
    $xml->docCompany('Greers.Org');
    $xml->docManager('Wife');

    /**
     * Choose to show any formatting/input errors on a seperate sheet
     */
    $xml->showErrorSheet(true);

    /**
     * Show the style options
     */
    $format1 = $xml->addStyle('left_rotate60_big');
    $format1->alignRotate(60);
    $format1->alignHorizontal('Left');
    $format1->fontSize('18');

    $format2 = $xml->addStyle('verticaltext_left');
    $format2->alignVerticaltext(45);
    $format2->alignHorizontal('Left');

    $format3 = $xml->addStyle('wraptext_top');
    $format3->alignWraptext();
    $format3->alignVertical('Top');

    /**
     * Create a new sheet with the XML document
     */
    $sheet1 = $xml->addSheet('Alignment');
    /**
     * Add three new cells of type String with difference alignment values.
     * Notice that the style of the each cell can be explicity named or the style
     * reference can be passed.
     */
    $sheet1->writeString(1,1,'left_rotate45',$format1);
    $sheet1->writeString(1,2,'vertical left','verticaltext_left');
    $sheet1->writeString(1,3,'this text has been wrapped and is aligned at the top','wraptext_top');
    $sheet1->writeString(1,4,'No style applied');


    $sheet2 = $xml->addSheet('Formulas');
    /**
     * Wrote three numbers.
     * Rows 4 and 5 show the formulas in R1C1 notation using the writeFormula()
     * function.
     * Also see how comments are added.
     */
    $sheet2->columnWidth(1,'100');
    $sheet2->writeString(1,1,'Number');
    $sheet2->writeNumber(1,2,50);
    $sheet2->writeString(2,1,'Number');
    $sheet2->writeNumber(2,2,30);
    $sheet2->writeString(3,1,'Number');
    $sheet2->writeNumber(3,2,20);
    $sheet2->writeString(4,1,'=SUM(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)');
    $sheet2->writeFormula('Number',4,2,'=SUM(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)');
    $sheet2->addComment(4,2,'Here is my formula: =SUM(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)','My NAME');
    $sheet2->writeString(5,1,'=SUM(R1C2:R3C2)');
    $sheet2->writeFormula('Number',5,2,'=SUM(R1C1:R3C2)');
    $sheet2->addComment(5,2,'Here is my formula: =SUM(R1C1:R3C2)');

    $sheet4 = $xml->addSheet('more formatting');
    $format4 = $xml->addStyle('my style');
    $format4->fontBold();
    $format4->fontItalic();
    $format4->fontUnderline('DoubleAccounting');
    $format4->bgColor('Black');
    $format4->fontColor('White');
    $format4->numberFormatDateTime();
    $mydate = $sheet4->convertMysqlDateTime('2008-02-14 19:30:00');
    $sheet4->writeDateTime(1,1,$mydate,$format4);
    // Change the row1 height to 30 pixels
    $sheet4->rowHeight(1,'30');
    $sheet4->writeString(2,1,'formatted text + cell color + merged + underlined',$format4);
    // Merge (2,1) with 4 columns to the right and 2 rows down
    $sheet4->cellMerge(2,1,4,2);
    exit;

    /**
     * Send the headers, then output the data
     */
    $xml->sendHeaders();
    $xml->writeData();

    ?>
```

Comment: There's an `exit;` towards the end of the file... try removing it?

Comment: I have done that; same problem. Thanks

Comment: How are you "running" this code -- is it from a web-browser or via command-line?

Comment: Via Webserver, I am using MAMP

Comment: Are there any PHP errors when this runs? (Check your `error_reporting` settings.)

Answer (score 0):

Try following **changes:**

```
$xml->writeData();


$xml->writeData([Path your file]);
```

If null **return xml**.